# How to include iTunesArtwork in resources folder when building with appcelerator/Titanium Studio build

Tags: ios, build, titanium, appcelerator, itunesartwork

I am trying to automate the process of including the iTunesArtwork file into my IOS build. I am using Titanium Studio to build my projects and want to have it place the iTunesArtwork file into the resources folder when it builds the IOS build. Does anyone know how to do this from inside Titanium Studio? The other files inside of the Resources folder are the info.plist and the Default.png(the splash screen).

I know I can do this manually in Xcode when I do the build from there, but I am attempting cut down the amount of manual work required to build the finished product.

Has anyone come across this before or know a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had just looked this up yesterday. I haven't tried it yet but here are the links i found that answered it:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-iOSgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions

if you have language specific:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-iOS